# In OrchardCms is there a way to change the layout module from 12 wide to 16 wide?

Tags: orchardcms, orchardcms-1.9

For some reason Semantic-ui's grid is 16 wide and I'm working on an Orchard Cms theme for that (couldn't find one elsewhere).

Comment: I don't think this is possible without rolling up your sleeves and doing some coding. You can customize the grid to use Bootstrap, there are tutorials out there, but that just gives a different template over the existing grid. The widgets in the sidebar are set up by the Layouts module and are preconfigured to 12 rows so they would need changing as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone else is looking.  I found that currently as of Orchard CMS 1.10.2 you can do this on the front-end but not the backend.

Here is an example of how the front-end grid was changed for bootstrap:  https://github.com/OrchardCMS/TheBootstrapMachine/tree/master/Views/Elements

And the reason you can't change the admin page grid: https://github.com/OrchardCMS/Orchard/blob/6720b71cf3474a9a7b8a8cc9a99d58b1e733acfa/src/Orchard.Web/Modules/Orchard.Layouts/Elements/Grid.cs#L6

As you can see 12 is hardset in the code.  I suppose you could extend the entire layout module, but this would be a lot of work because several other modules depend on it.

I plan to use Semantic-ui anyway but using their grid using this nomenclature:

```
<div class="ui twelve column grid">
    <div class="four wide column">four</div>
    <div class="four wide column">four</div>
    <div class="four wide column">four</div>
</div>
```